# JavaSocket Read Hangs on HTTP Call

Tags: java, deadlock, flickr

I am building a collection program in Java that collects data from websites using their apis. I am encountering this problem where it will hang on an http call. I tried to work around it by executing an http call over an executor service with a timeout. That doesn't seem to work as it would keep timing out and retrying. I figured it might be something to do with the API so after a retry I would reinitialize a whole new object per website API. Still no solution. I am trying to identify the root cause of this but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Here is a look at my flickr manager class that handles the calls to flickr.

```
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException;

import com.flickr4java.flickr.Flickr;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrException;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.FlickrRuntimeException;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.REST;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.RequestContext;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.auth.Auth;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.auth.Permission;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.people.User;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.Exif;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.Extras;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.Photo;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.PhotoList;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.SearchParameters;
import com.flickr4java.flickr.photos.Size;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

public class FlickrManager {
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FlickrManager.class.getName());
    private final static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
    private Flickr flickr;
    private final int MAX_PER_PAGE = 500;
    private final RateLimiter rateLimiter;

    private String ApiKey;
    private String ApiSecret;
    private String authToken;
    private String authTokenSecret;

    private Integer hostPort;
    private String hostAddress;
    private String httpScheme;

    public FlickrManager(Flickr flickr, double apiCallsPerSecond) throws FlickrException {
        this.flickr = flickr;
        flickr.getTestInterface().echo(Collections.emptyMap());
        //get flickr info to reinitialize flickr object if necessary
        this.ApiKey = flickr.getApiKey();
        this.ApiSecret = flickr.getSharedSecret();
        this.hostPort = flickr.getTransport().getPort();
        this.hostAddress = flickr.getTransport().getHost();
        this.httpScheme = flickr.getTransport().getScheme();
        if(flickr.getAuth() != null){
            this.authToken = flickr.getAuth().getToken();
            this.authTokenSecret = flickr.getAuth().getTokenSecret();
        }
        this.rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(apiCallsPerSecond);
    }

    private void initialize(){
        this.flickr = null;
        REST rest = new REST(this.hostAddress,this.hostPort);
        rest.setScheme(this.httpScheme);
        this.flickr = new Flickr(this.ApiKey, this.ApiSecret,rest);
        if(this.authToken != null && this.authTokenSecret != null){
            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
            Auth auth = new Auth();
            auth.setPermission(Permission.READ);
            auth.setToken(this.authToken);
            auth.setTokenSecret(this.authTokenSecret);
            requestContext.setAuth(auth);
            flickr.setAuth(auth);
        }

    }

    public User getUserInfo(String flickrProfileId) throws FlickrException{
        return doFlickrAction(new CallableFlickrTask<User>(){
            @Override
            public User execute() throws FlickrException {
                return flickr.getPeopleInterface().getInfo(flickrProfileId);
            }
        });
    }

    public PhotoList<Photo> search(SearchParameters params, int page) throws FlickrException{
        return doFlickrAction(new CallableFlickrTask<PhotoList<Photo>>(){
            @Override
            public PhotoList<Photo> execute() throws FlickrException {
                return flickr.getPhotosInterface().search(params, MAX_PER_PAGE, page);
            }
        });
    }

    public PhotoList<Photo> getUserPhotos(String userNSID, int page) throws FlickrException{
        return doFlickrAction(new CallableFlickrTask<PhotoList<Photo>>(){
            @Override
            public PhotoList<Photo> execute() throws FlickrException {
                return flickr.getPeopleInterface().getPhotos(
                        userNSID, 
                        null, null, null, null, null, 
                        Flickr.CONTENTTYPE_PHOTO, null, 
                        Extras.ALL_EXTRAS, 100, page);
            }
        });
    }

    //Catch the execption inside the function for failure to get exif 
    public Collection<Exif> getPhotoExif(Photo photo) throws FlickrException, FlickrRuntimeException {
        return doFlickrAction(new CallableFlickrTask<Collection<Exif>>(){
            @Override
            public Collection<Exif> execute() throws FlickrException {
                return flickr.getPhotosInterface().getExif(photo.getId(),photo.getSecret());
            }
        });
    }

    public Collection<Size> getAvailablePhotoSizes(Photo photo) throws FlickrException{
        return doFlickrAction(new CallableFlickrTask<Collection<Size>>(){
            @Override
            public Collection<Size> execute() throws FlickrException  {
                return flickr.getPhotosInterface().getSizes(photo.getId());
            }
        });
    }

    private abstract class CallableFlickrTask<T> {
        public abstract T execute() throws FlickrException, FlickrRuntimeException;
    }


    private <T> T doFlickrAction(CallableFlickrTask<T> callable) throws FlickrException {
        while(true){
            rateLimiter.acquire();
            Future<T> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<T>() {
                @Override
                public T call() throws Exception {
                return callable.execute();
            }});

            try {
                return future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Interrupted exception: {0}",e.getMessage());
                initialize(); //initialize if it's been interupted
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                if(     cause instanceof UnknownHostException || 
                        cause instanceof SocketException || 
                        cause instanceof OAuthConnectionException ){
                    //sleep and retry
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Unknown Host or Socket exception. Retry: {0}",e.getMessage());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        initialize();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Thread sleep was interrupted exception: {0}", ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } 
                //if it's not of the above exceptions, then rethrow
                else if (cause instanceof FlickrException) {
                    throw (FlickrException) cause; 
                } 
                else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO,"Timeout Exception: {0}",e.getMessage());
                initialize(); //initialize again after timeout
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I also used jvisualvm to get a look at what the collection is doing while it's hanging. The thread dump is here: [Thread dump](http://pastebin.com/exeBpgeY)

Comment: You mean it hangs? Deadlock is a different thing. I suggest monitoring the network traffic to see what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, it's been changed. I don't even know the first thing to look for when monitoring network traffic. Would be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Uh sure. *Points finger at Google*